# MYSQL ERROR 2003 (HY000) (113) in SSH remote tunneling, but telnet from SSH tunnel works

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, database-connection, tunneling

I have spent all day trying to solve this.
The thing I want to do is that:
I have a MYSQL server, namely A with CentOS 7, in a private network, cannot be NAT or connected to VPN. Now I want to access this server from a remote machine, namely B with CentOS 6. I have ssh access to machine B remotely, and ssh access to machine A locally.

This approach I tried is to use SSH tunneling.
On machine A terminal:

```
ssh -R 9001:localhost:3306 user@B
```

Then on B, I tried

```
mysql --port=9001 -u root -p
```

which gives

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql-server-1' (113)
```

Firstly I though it could be firewall or privileges, but then I connected A to public network physically with address, say C, which is a different network from B, and I can simpy use from B straight away

```
mysql -hC -u root -p
```

and it works without any problem.

Back to tunneling,
I tried to telnet after SSH tunneling from A to B

```
ssh -R 9001:localhost:3306 user@B
telnet localhost 9001
```

which gives me

```
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
V
5.5.44-MariaDB-log)Gjb+N'u��;cbDkng;1!RXmysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.
-bash-4.1$
```

which seems to be something good, but I get the 2003 ERROR anyway.

Any thought of this? Maybe there is another work around to this problem?

P.S. I have tested all answer I could find, and the SSH tunnel works well with socket of other programs.

Comment: I used other ways such as JDBC to connect to MYSQL server from B to A using SSH tunnel and it works. Only Mysql client seems not working in this situation. Very weird. And well not important for now since I will use other connectors rather than mysql-client from now on.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the IP address of your local machine, from which you are trying to access mysql through VPN has privileges to access the database.

```
mysql> select host,user,password from mysql.user;
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| host | user | password                                  |
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| %    | abcd | *9B3E7610FB431631340BD618E58D49DF1928A251 |
| %    | sync | *1747319F3F87039C382597515F8742920D9B75D1 |
| %    | root | *FAAFFE644E901CFAFAEC7562415E5FAEC243B8B2 |
+------+------+-------------------------------------------+
```

Make sure that there is an entry for the ip address of local machine  for the user through which you are logging in. You can also use % in the host field. % denotes all users.

You can add privileges through the following command

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'root'@'%' identified by <password>.
mysql> flush privileges
```