# ssh tunnel in foreground works for mysql host localhost and 127.0.0.1 but ssh-tunnel in background doesn't work

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

So this is similar to my previous question, except now 127.0.0.1 does not work either: [ssh tunnel in foreground works for mysql host localhost but ssh-tunnel in background works for mysql host 127.0.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50948117/ssh-tunnel-in-foreground-works-for-mysql-host-localhost-but-ssh-tunnel-in-backgr/50950579#50950579)

```
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to machine-two-hostname.com ([###.##.##.##]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:3360 forwarded to remote address localhost:3360
debug3: channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: type 2 wildcard 0 addr NULL
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 3360.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 4 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 3360.
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
```

It occassionally does "keepalive" which I think is normal:

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 82
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype keepalive@openssh.com want_reply 1
debug3: send packet: type 82
```

The command I ran was:

```
ssh -vvvvv -fN -L 3360:localhost:3360 admin@machine-two-hostname.com
```

all connections through the background ssh tunnel are refused but I can connect fine through the foreground one:

```
$ mysql -uroot -proot -h127.0.0.1
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111 "Connection refused")
```

UPDATE: I am using mysql-client this answer might be related:
[MYSQL ERROR 2003 (HY000) (113) in SSH remote tunneling, but telnet from SSH tunnel works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36075336/mysql-error-2003-hy000-113-in-ssh-remote-tunneling-but-telnet-from-ssh-tunn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using port 3360 MySQL is on port 3306.